# Sitecore 10.3 (PaaS) - SOLR Core not created

Tags: azure, paas, sitecore-install-assistant

I have installed `Sitecore 10.3` using `Sitecore Experience Cloud` (market place) on Azure PaaS.

`SOLR` (SOLR version - 8.11.2) instance is available on `Azure App Service`.

My Sitecore installation went well and can see that vanilla instance is working fine.

[image]

Only Issue I can see is, I am not finding any SOLR core available.

[image]

Even I am not finding any core in SOLR as well:

[image]

I checked connectionString file as well and found that SOLR connectionString mentioned is correct and it is opening SOLR dashboard.

Can someone guide what could be wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find anything in logs? When you click on the schema populate, you must get something in logs.

Comment: I found error: 

ERROR [Index=sitecore_web_index] DefaultSolrSearchIndexesInitializer: Initialization has failed.

Comment: It was the known issue for Sitecore 9.3 and fixed are available https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0954302.. Should I use this for Sitecore 10.3 as well?

Answer (score 2):

It is not expected that Solr cores were created during the installation for PaaS deployments as mentioned in the documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--deploying-a-new-sitecore-environment-to-the-microsoft-azure-app-service.html

> The Solr server is not provisioned by an ARM template, therefore after
> deploying to Azure, you must manually create a template and [populate
> it with Solr cores](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/walkthrough--setting-up-solr.html).

The linked document under "populate it with Solr cores" should have the necessary steps to complete the installation.

However, the version of the article for Sitecore 10.2-10.3 doesn't contain this note, which is an issue in the documentation. I have already raised the issue with Sitecore support to correct the documentation.

But, to answer your question, you need to manually create and populate the Solr cores.

Comment: Thanks Raman for this detail. Let me try and will inform here. thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Raman. This works for me. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, Jitendra. If this works for you, feel free to mark this answer as accepted.